# Interactive SVG not showing

Tags: svg

I have a problem with implementation interactive svg to our website.

In the page edit view (elementor) the file works fine, it displays and there is an animation on hover. But after save and check live there is a white background on the page.

The svg file is generetated from SolidWorks Composer.

Here's the code:
https://pastebin.com/iVH9jqPn

Here's the website link:
http://bitly.pl/0PPO0